# how to control edge placements and labels in dot (graphviz)

Tags: label, graphviz, dot, directed-graph, edges

I have trouble controlling the layout of graphviz.
Trying to produce a simple automaton. 
The source:

```
digraph mygraph {
rankdir=LR;
size="13,13"
node [shape = circle];
init   -> Ready  [ label = "" ];

Ready -> P1  [ label = "t<T\n----TexT----" ];
P1  -> Ready [ label = "t>T" ];
P1  -> B1    [ label = "t<T" ];
B1  -> P1    [ label = "----TexT----" ];
B1  -> U1    [ label = "----TexT----" ];

Ready -> P2  [ label = "t<T\n----TexT----" ];
P2 -> Ready  [ label = "t>T" ];
P2 -> B2     [ label = "t<T" ];
B2 -> P2     [ label = "----TexT----" ];
B2 -> U2     [ label = "----TexT----" ];


U1  -> Ready [ label = "----TexT----", constraint=false];
U2  -> Ready [ label = "----TexT----", constraint=false];

P1 -> P2 [ label = "t<T\n----TexT----", constraint=false];
P2 -> P1 [ label = "t<T\n----TexT----", constraint=false];
}
```

trouble is, the labels are intertwined. I probably need:
1. larger spacing
2. move some of the edges up
3. control label placings

how do I do it?
[image: graph.png]

Answer (score 2):

Since the conflict occurs on vertical edges going in opposite directions between nodes placed by dot on the same rank (P1 & P2) you could use vertical rank direction (drop the "rankdir=LR" line) so that the labels for theses specific edges are placed one below the other rather than side by side.

Granted, it's not a universal cure for this sort of issues but should help here without unnecessarily bloating the graph (which increasing node separation via "nodesep" would do).

Comment: Thanks. Removing the rankdir did improve things, but it's rather annoying. I liked the previous node placement.